# Why Entity Framework inserting null value?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, edmx

I have set `DeletedFlag` column as `Not Null` in database. I have also changed `Conceptual Model` and `Storage Model` accordingly. Both has column definition as

```
<Property Name="DeletedFlag" Type="Boolean" Nullable="false" DefaultValue="false"/>
```

still EF trying to insert null in this field hence throwing exception.

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DeletedFlag', table
>   'xxxxx.dbo.TblUsers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

**PS** I can't update my model from database because it will mess up many things.

Comment: what is the db type of `DeletedFlag` column? i would expect a bit data type

Comment: what approach did you use? db first or code first? since you are using EF don't touch the underlying generated codes. Edit the .edmx file instead so mapping is clear and concise

Comment: in your User class, what is the type of DeletedFlag ?

Comment: @tschmit007 it's bool

Comment: I meant the CLR type in the c#/VB class

Comment: @tschmit007 Nullable<global::System.Boolean>

Comment: this is the point: in this case the defautl value is null, not false. You must use a non nullable type to conform your data model